# How to run .so files using through python script

Tags: python, cython, shared-objects

I have a c program(.c file). I am converting that to a shared object(.so). How can i call and run the shared object from my python code? If possible, please suggest me a list of libraries that can help me to do this task.

Comment: Is the C library _meant_ to be called from Python?

Comment: I just wanted to execute the file, some thing like calling a python function with out parameters and storing the result in a python variable for further execution in python. Hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: SWIG is very easy to use: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to call functions inside a shared object, the the standard module [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) is what you are after. No need for any external libraries.

Load a library:

```
from ctypes import *
# either
libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
# or
libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
```

Then call a function from the library, the same as calling a Python function:

```
print(libc.time(None))
```

Comment: It is ok but not so elagant. The best solution should allow user to directly import it.

Answer (score 4):

Caution to those using the recommended method. It doesnt work on windows and is for linux the code for the windows function is as follows :

```
from ctypes import *
libc = cdll.msvcrt
```

and to call it,

```
print(libc.time(None))
```

Comment: You too are totally off-topic. Read the question again. It speaks about .so files.

Answer (score 0):

If the .so file exposes a `PyInit_<module_name>` function, its path (or parent directory's path) can be added to the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. Then you can import the module via `import <module_name>`. Note: it looks like the name of the .so file must match the module name `<module_name>` that's exposed.

More information here: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html

Adding this answer for reference.